# p-adic integers, isomorphism, proof explanation

Tags: proof-explanation, p-adic-number-theory

I am studying the following proof and need some help at some points.
While going through the proof, I numerate my questions, to refer to them at the end.
For the notation note, that $U_n=1+p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $U=\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$ (the group of p-adic units).

Theorem:

If $p\neq 2$, $U_1$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$.
If $p=2, U_1=\{\pm 1\}\times U_2$ and $U_2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Proof:

Consider first the case $p\neq 2$.
Choose an element $\alpha\in U_1- U_2$, for example $\alpha=1+p$. (1)

By the lemma:

> Let $x\in U_n- U_{n+1}$ with $n\geq 1$ if $p\neq 2$ and $n\geq 2$ if $p=2$. Then $x^p\in U_{n+1}- U_{n+2}$

we have $\alpha^{p^i}\in U_{i+1}- U_{i+2}$.
Let $\alpha_n$ be the image of $\alpha$ in $U_1/ U_n$.
We have $\alpha_n^{p^{n-2}}\neq 1$ and $\alpha_n^{p^{n-1}}=1$. (2)
But $U_1/ U_n$ is of order $p-1$, hence it is a cyclic group generated by $\alpha_n$.

Now denote by $\theta_{n,\alpha}:\mathbb{Z}/p^{n-1}\mathbb{Z}\to U_1/U_n$ the isomorphism $z\mapsto \alpha_n^z$.

The diagram:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z} @>{\theta_{n+1,\alpha}}>> U_1/U_{n+1}\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\mathbb{Z}/p^{n-1}\mathbb{Z} @>{\theta_{n,\alpha}}>> U_1/U_n
\end{CD}

is commutative.
From this one sees that the $\theta_{n,\alpha}$ define an isomorphism (3)
$\theta:\mathbb{Z}_p\to U_1$ hence the proposition for $p\neq 2$.

Suppose now that $p=2$. 
Choose $\alpha\in U_2- U_3$, that is $\alpha\equiv 5\mod 8$. (4)
Define as above isomorphism $\theta_\alpha:\mathbb{Z}_2\to U_2$. 
On the other hand, the homomorphism $U_1\to U_1\setminus U_2\cong\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ induces an isomorphism of $\{\pm 1\}$ onto $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ (5)

From this we get $U_1=\{\pm 1\}\times U_2$

Questions:

(1)

It appears that the choice of $\alpha\in U_1-U_2$ is free, since the given lemma we get always a generator of the cyclic group for every $x\in U_1-U_2$ as long as $x\neq 1$.

(2)

The image of $\alpha$ in $U_1/U_n$ is given by $\alpha_n\mod (1+p^n\mathbb{Z}_p)$. 
What can we say about $\alpha_n$? Holds $\alpha_n\equiv 1\mod p^n$?

How can we see, that $\alpha_n^{p^{n-2}}\neq 1$ and $\alpha_n^{p^{n-1}}=1$?
Why is this enough to see, that $U_1/U_n$ is cyclic.

I guess, that $\alpha_n^{p^{n-1}}=1$ and $\alpha_n^{p^{n-2}}=\alpha_n\neq 1$ ensues from Fermat's little theorem. Am I right?

(3)

How exactly do we get the isomorphism $\theta:\mathbb{Z}_p\to U_1$

It is $\mathbb{Z}_p=\displaystyle{\lim_{\leftarrow}}~ \mathbb{Z}/p^{n-1}\mathbb{Z}$ and $U_1=\displaystyle{\lim_{\leftarrow}}~ U_1/U_n$

I see that we can extend the diagram and reduce $p^{n}$ any further until $n=0$.
But how do we get the projective limit? We get finite isomorphisms, but is that enough for the projective limit?

(4)

Why is for $\alpha\in U_2-U_3$ that $\alpha\equiv 5\mod 8$. 
$\alpha\in 1+4\mathbb{Z}_2$ that means $\alpha\equiv 1\mod 4$. Since $\alpha\notin (1+8\mathbb{Z}_2)$ it is $\alpha\not\equiv 1\mod 8$ which means, that $\alpha\equiv 5\mod 8$.

(5)

We define an isomorphism $\theta_\alpha: \mathbb{Z}_2\to U_1$ as above. That is clear.
How do we see from the homomorphism $U_1\to U_1/U_2\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$
That we get an isomorphism from $\{\pm 1\}\to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

How do we see that $U_1/U_2\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$?

I want to give a function $f: U_1\to\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ which is surjective and has kernel $U_2$.
Can this be done by $\alpha\mapsto \alpha\mod 4$? I am struggeling with the elements of the form $1+2\mathbb{Z}_2=U_1$. We can not say, that $U_1\cong 1+\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, can we?

Thanks in advance for your help and comments.

Comment: Not really an answer to your questions, but I think there is a "standard" proof  based on the exp and log function on the $p$-adic fields.

Comment: Do you have a source for that?

Comment: You may refer to Neukirch's "Algebraic Number Theory". And I remember the proof is also contained in Iwasawa's "local class field theory" .

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I find these books at my university.

Comment: Thank you for transcribing the argument into MathJax so that the question is self-contained for posterity.  However, it would be good to also cite the source of your material, which appears to be Serre's *Course in Arithmetic* (a favourite of mine).

Comment: Yes, the source is Serre's Course in Arithmetic, which can be found here: https://www.math.purdue.edu/~lipman/MA598/Serre-Course%20in%20Arithmetic.pdf. I tried to give everything which is needed for the proof.

Comment: Neukirch's book is freely available here- http://www.cimat.mx/~luis/seminarios/Teoria-de-Numeros/Neukirch_Algebraic_number_theory.pdf

Comment: Do you know why this question does not have any answer yet? Are the questions unclear, or to many? You can also just answer a few, if you consider to answer the question but do not want to answer them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you managed to confuse yourself quite a bit over it, so let's start with simple things. Forget about $p=2$ altogether (it just there to complicate every step by a special case; you can return to it later once you figured the rest out).

1) Yes, you can take anything in $U_1\setminus U_2$ though the condition $x\in U_1\setminus U_2$ is much stronger than $x\ne 1$. It means $x=1+yp+\dots$ for some "$p$-adic digit" $y\ne 0$.

2) $\alpha_n$ is the full remainder of $\alpha$ modulo $p^n$, so it is just the first $n$ digits of $\alpha$ (compare with the standard decimal representation; if you go modulo $10^n$, you just operate on the last $n$ digits ignoring all transfers to higher positions; $p$-adic integers are the same, just infinite and written low to high powers instead of high to low in the decimal notation. Obviously $\alpha_n\ne 1\mod p^n$. Note that $U_1/U_n$ is the *multiplicative* group (compare to the multiplicative group of last $n$ decimal digits of numbers ending in $1$).

$\alpha_n^{p^{n-2}}$ is the equivalence class of $\alpha^{p^{n-2}}\in U_{n-1}\setminus U_n$, so it is definitely not $1$ in $U_1/U_n$ (the $n$-th digit is still not $0$) but the next raising to the power $p$ will kill it.

$U_1/U_n$ has exactly $p^{n-1}$ elements (the first digit is $1$ and you have $p$ choices for each of the remaining $n-1$ digits. So, you have a finite group of order $p^{n-1}$ and an element $\alpha_n$ in it that has exactly the same order (recall that the order of any group element is a divisor of the group order and we have just excluded any divisor of $p^{n-1}$ strictly less than $p^{n-1}$. Thus, all powers of $\alpha^n$ from $0$ to $p^{n-1}-1$ are different and thus cover the whole group once.

(3) We can use this isomorphism $(Z_p/p^{n-1}Z_p,+)\ni z\mapsto \alpha_n^z\in (U_1/U_n,\times)$ to define the $n$ digits of $\theta(z)$ from the $n-1$ digits of $z$ and vice versa. The diagram shows that this process is consistent in the sense that getting more digits with larger $n$ doesn't change the digits we obtained with smaller $n$. So, in order to obtain the $n$-th digit we can just use any $\theta_m$ with $m>n$ with the same result.
This is indeed called something I don't remember what in algebra but the story is merely that you try to define a function that maps infinite sequences to infinite sequences from functions that tell you how to get the first $n$ elements of the output sequence from the first $n$ elements in the input sequence in a consistent way.

I'll stop here for now. Hope it helps a bit. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I quite do not understand what you write in (3). The diagram is reducing the $n$. Should it not go up to get an infinite series, therefore a p-adic integer?

Comment: @Cornman Yes you should, but who prevents you from reading the diagram from the bottom to the top instead of from the top to the bottom? (meaning that the next diagram that you should think of is not the one in which $n+1$ is replaced by $n$ but the one in which $n$ is replaced by $n+1$ and you should stack them up, not down)

Comment: Ah, ok. That makes sense. Could you give a little bit more insight on how the "final" isomorphism looks like? Or to be more specific how we conclude that we get $\theta: \mathbb{Z}_p\to U_1$

Comment: @Cornman Not too much: in order to figure out just the $n$-th digit of the output, you need to know all the $n-1$ digits in the input. The formal story is that to know $\theta(z)$ in $\mathbb Z_p$ is equivalent to knowing it in all $\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$ and you are told how to find it there if you know $z$ in $\mathbb Z/ p^{n-1}\mathbb Z$ for each $n$. That information is always enough to determine $\theta(z)$ uniquely and allows to conclude that it exists if it is consistent. On the other hand, if you think of real analysis, can you give me some insight on what $x\mapsto e^x$ looks like?

Comment: Thank you. If you now go over the questions (4) and (5). You can have the 100 reputations. :) I already showed that $U_1/U_2\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @Cornman As to (4),your explanation there is perfectly correct. As to (5), I'm not quite sure what exactly is your problem. You have one misprint: the isomorphism is from $\mathbb Z_2$ to $U_2$, not to $U_1$. After that you just have to show that $U_1$ isomorphic to $U_2\times\{-1,1\}$. Is it this last step that gives you trouble or is it something else? If it is, all that happens there is that $-1=(1,1,1,1,\dots)\in U_1\setminus U_2$ and $(-1)^2=1$, so each element $z\in U_1$ is either in $U_2$ or in $(-1)U_2$ (depending on the second digit) and the multiplication behaves as it should.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for the misprint.